# javascript FileAttachment is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'am trying to read a csv file with `D3` and `FileAttachment`.

I have something like this:

`data = d3.csvParse(await FileAttachment("data.csv").text(), d3.autoType)`

But I got this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: FileAttachment is not defined`

My index.html is this.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@observablehq/stdlib@3"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <p id="main_title">Some title</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        console.log(FileAttachment("data/my_data.csv"))
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `<script>'https://static.observablehq.com/index-def8ae9d.js'</script>` be `<script src="https://static.observablehq.com/index-def8ae9d.js"></script>`?

Comment: That didn't work